# What is the purpose of adding scope modifiers to @Components in Dagger2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, scope, dagger-2

Say I have a class (or a `@Provides` method) annotated with `@Singleton`. This makes sense to me, whenever a dependency is provided from this class, the same instance will always be returned.

What I am trying to understand is why there is then a requirement for components that use that module to also be marked as `@Singleton`. The purpose of adding a scope to a component does not make sense to me. A component is an interface, that dagger uses to implement the actual injection.

If I try to compile my app with my dependency class marked as `@Singleton`, but do not have `@Singleton` marked on a component that injects this dependency, I get an error.

```
com.example.whatever.MyComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components
```

Adding `@Singleton` to the component makes this error go away, but I want to understand why. Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@Singleton` on your component allows you to use `@Singleton` on your provider methods in your module you specify for your component. Scoped providers make it so that you can have only one instance from that given module without any additional magic beyond what Dagger2 generates for you.

```
@Singleton
@Component(module={BlahModule.class})
public interface SingletonComponent {
    Blah blah();
}

@Module
public class BlahModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Blah blah() {
        return new BlahImpl();
    }
}
```

Comment: So adding @Singleton to a component just says the modules I use may provide singletons? Why does the Component need to know that the dependency it is injecting is a singleton? If a FooObject needs a LoggerObject, it should not need to care if it is passed the only LoggerObject, or the 1000th LoggerObject, no? I think I am still not understanding the *why*.

Comment: So that the modules you provide don't mix scopes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Dagger 2 design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fwg-NsMKYtYxeEWe82rISIHjNrtdqonfiHgp8-PQ7m8/edit#heading=h.pk0mr6enxl9x), it is meant to make intention clear ("a *declaration of intention*") and to allow for better compile-time checking.

> That declaration enables dagger to enforce the following constraints:
>
> - A given component may only have bindings (including scope annotations
>     on classes) that are unscoped or of the declared scope. I.e. a
>     component cannot represent two scopes.  When no scope is listed,
>     bindings may only be unscoped.
> - A scoped component may only have one
>     scoped dependency.  This is the mechanism that enforces that two
>     components don’t each declare their own scoped binding.  E.g. Two
>     Singleton components that each have their own @Singleton Cache would
>     be broken.
> - The scope for a component must not appear in any of its
>     transitive dependencies.  E.g.: SessionScoped -> RequestScoped ->
>     SessionScoped doesn’t make any sense and is a bug.
> - Singleton is
>     treated specially in that it cannot have any scoped dependencies. 
>     Everyone expects Singleton to be the “root”.

This also makes some sense given the implementation of Dagger 2: Because Scopes are implemented via memoization and the user is responsible for instantiating a new Component instance for every new scope, then it makes sense that the Component has a lifetime (and set of provisions) to which the scope also applies.